# Golang type derived from base type assignment problem

Tags: go, types, casting

I would like to understand the reason for the error assigning a variable of a type derived from a base type with a value of that base type.
Assuming it is possible to make the assignment, please explain how to do it.

```
type blah uint64

func main() {

    var num uint64 = 55
    var myb blah = num
}
```

When run I get:
`cannot use num (type uint64) as type blah in assignment`

Comment: `var myb blah = blah(num)`

Comment: This is a deliberate decision of the go language. It forces you to be explicit about the type by doing a type cast, so that you don't mix them up accidentally. This is, for example, useful for enums, where you want to avoid someone to pass invalid numbers instead of the correct enum constants

Answer (score 3):

Even though `uint64` is the base type of `blah` Go doesn't convert it implicitly, you need to make an explicit cast (convertion). As mentioned in the comments, do `var myb blah = blah(num)`. With `blah(num)` you say 'I want `num` to be converted to type `blah`'.